# TextInputSkin - strange behaviour inside ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, flex-spark

I have the following problem using two TextInput fields inside an ItemRenderer.

```
<s:temRenderer>
    <s:HGroup id="listEntry" height="100%" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:TextInput id="damageArea" width="100%" click="this.textFieldClicked(event)" 
                     skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"/>
        <s:TextInput id="damageType" width="100%" click="this.textFieldClicked(event)" 
                     skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:itemRenderer>
```

The function `textFieldClicked(event:Event)` stops the propagation of the event, so the focus remains on the `InputText`.

My problem is that without `TextInputSkin` there are some rendering problems with the text inside the `InputText` when the soft keyboard pops up - it just disappears, or is placed somewhere else on the display.

With `TextInputSkin` everything is fine, but I can only select the first two characters. On doubletap it selects the entire Text, then the soft keyboard pops up and the selection changes to the first two characters. I tried to call the function `selectAll()` afterwards, but this one also only selects the first two characters of the text.

I am using the ItemRenderer for a List. Outside of the List this problem does not appear.

Is there any solution for this one?

Comment: You have two TextInputs with the same id. How are you not getting compiler errors??

Comment: Actually not - I made a mistake while copy the code here. Edited. Sorry